# Hashtable & BST Implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, hashtable, binary-search-tree

I'm working on an assignment that can accept commands from keyboard to insert people into a hashtable. After someone is inserted into the hastable, they can be "friended" with another person in the table. The way I have to store who is friends with who is a binary search tree. What I have to do is for the hashtable the first part of the node would be the person's name, then then next is a pointer to the bst for that person's friends, and finally the end is a pointer to the next node for chaining if there is a collision. Here is a visual example...
[image]

I have been able to insert people into my table, but the problem that I can not figure out is how to access the BST and add in friends for that person. Here is my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Structures
struct linkedList{
    char *name;
    struct linkedList *next;
    struct linkedList *tree;
};

typedef struct linkedList list;

struct hashTable{
    int size;
    list **table;
};

typedef struct hashTable hash;

struct bst{
    char *val;
    struct bst *l;
    struct bst *r;
};

int main(){
char input[50];
char *ch, cmd_str[50], name[30];

// Make hash table for names
hash *profiles;
profiles = createHashTable(1001);

while(1){
    // Get keyboard input
    fgets(input, 50, stdin);
    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';

    // parse the input
    ch = strtok(input, " ");
    strcpy(cmd_str,ch);



    if(strcmp("CREATE", cmd_str) == 0){
        ch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        insertPerson(profiles, ch);
    }
    else if(strcmp("FRIEND", cmd_str) == 0){
        ch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        strcpy(name, ch);
        ch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        friendPerson(profiles, name, ch);
    }
    else if(strcmp("UNFRIEND", cmd_str) == 0){
        ch = strtok(NULL, " \n");

    }
    else if(strcmp("LIST", cmd_str) == 0){
        ch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        printFriends(profiles, ch);
    }
    else if(strcmp("QUERY", cmd_str) == 0){

    }
    else if(strcmp("BIGGEST-FRIEND-CIRCLE", cmd_str) == 0){

    }
    else if(strcmp("INFLUENTIAL-FRIEND", cmd_str) == 0){

    }
    else if(strcmp("EXIT", cmd_str) == 0){
        printf("\nExiting...\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("\nBad Command.\n");
    }
}
}

// Creates Hash Table
hash *createHashTable(int size){
int i;
hash *new_table;

if((new_table = malloc(sizeof(hash))) == NULL)
    return NULL;

if((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(list *) * size)) == NULL)
    return NULL;

for(i=0; i < size; i++)
    new_table->table[i] = NULL;

new_table->size = size;

return new_table;
}

// hashing function
int keyHash(char *name){
    int c;
    unsigned long key;

    while(c = *name++)
        key = ((key<<5) + key) + c;

    return key%1000;
 }

// insert a person into the hash table
void insertPerson(hash *profiles, char *name){
    struct linkedList *item = (struct linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    int hash_val = keyHash(name);

    item->name = name;
    item->next = NULL;
    item->tree = new_tree;

    // Collision case
    if(profiles->table[hash_val] != NULL){
        while(profiles->table[hash_val]->next != NULL){
            profiles->table[hash_val] = profiles->table[hash_val]->next;
        }
        profiles->table[hash_val]->next = item;
    }
    // Empty cell
    else{
        profiles->table[hash_val] = item;
    }

}

// friend two people inside the hash table
void friendPerson(hash *profiles, char *name, char *_friend){
    int hash1 = keyHash(name);
    int hash2 = keyHash(_friend);

    // check if the names are already in system
    if(!profiles->table[hash1]){
        printf("%s is not yet in the system", name);
        return;
    }
    if(!profiles->table[hash2]){
        printf("%s is not yet in the system", _friend);
        return;
    }

    // add first friend
    if(strcmp(profiles->table[hash1]->name, name) == 0){
        insertBST(profiles->table[hash1]->tree, _friend);
    }
    else{
        while(profiles->table[hash1]->next != NULL){
            if(strcmp(profiles->table[hash1]->name, name) == 0)){
                break;
            }
            profiles->table[hash1] = profiles->table[hash1]->next;
        }
        insertBST(profiles->table[hash1]->tree, _friend);
    }

    // add second friend
    if(strcmp(profiles->table[hash2]->name, _friend) == 0){
        insertBST(profiles->table[hash2]->tree, name);
    }
    else{
        while(profiles->table[hash2]->next != NULL){
            if(strcmp(profiles->table[hash2]->name, name) == 0)){
                break;
            }
            profiles->table[hash2] = profiles->table[hash1]->next;
        }
        insertBST(profiles->table[hash2]->tree, name);
    }
}

// creates a new bst node
struct bst *newBSTNode(char *name){
    struct bst *temp = (struct bst* )malloc(sizeof(struct bst));
    temp->val = strdup(name);
    strcpy(temp->val, name);
    temp->l = temp->r = NULL;
    return temp;
}

// Inserts the a friend into a BST
struct bst *insertBST(struct bst *node, char *name){
    if(!node)
        return newBSTNode(name);
    else{
        if(strcmp(name, node->val) < 0){
            node->l = insertBST(node->l, name);
        }
        else if(strcmp(name, node->val) > 0){
            node->r = insertBST(node->r, name);
        }
    }

    return node;
}

// Inorder print of names
void inorder(struct bst *root){
    if(!root){
         inorder(root->l);
         printf("%s ", root->val);
         inorder(root->r);
    }
}

// Sends to function to print names
void printFriends(hash *profiles, char *name){
    int hash_val = keyHash(name);
    inorder(profiles->table[hash_val]->tree);
}
```

How would I be able to access the BST of said person? The `struct bst *tree = profiles->table[hash1]->tree;` was my previous attempt, but it was more of a shot in the dark. Thanks in advance!

Update: Okay, so I have been able to add friends (I think) and now I'm trying to print them with `void printFriends()`. However when I run the function nothing prints out. Would anyone know where I'm messing it up? I've updated the code above.

Comment: Maybe changing the type of the `tree` in the struct `linkedList` to `bst` would help?

Comment: `friend` is not a keyword in C. You don't have to use `_friend` unless you've got some non-obvious coding standard.

Comment: You're both right! I was just using `_friend` to be safe. However, it is very good to know fro the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `linkedList` stores the `name` and a `tree` pointer. But the type of `tree` is `linkedList`. Change that to `struct bst *`. You'll have to reorder the declarations, or insert a forward declaration.

Implement a search. You check if the hash buckets are empty, but you don't search for the matching name.

Once you find a matching name in the bucket, the same node contains the aforementioned `tree` pointer. Insert the friend in the tree. Depending on your logic, you may or may not want to insert a backreference in the other person's tree. (If Alice is friends with Bob, does that make Bob friends with Alice automatically? Or wait for confirmation?)

Comment: Such a easy change! Basically I could use `profiles->table[hash1]->tree` to get the root then. Thank you for pointing it out. Yes, I will defiantly have to do a back reference to the other person's tree. When you friend/un-friend someone it is automatically changed. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: I ran into another problem with actually adding a friend to the tree. Would you mind giving it another look? I updated my code and also the problem. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You're still not searching for collisions. Look at your example picture - if Sam and Liza both hash to the same bucket, you need to traverse the list to find the right string.

Comment: And I think your condition in `inorder` is wrong. You're doing everything guarded by `if (!root)` which is basically `if (root == NULL)`. I suspect you want `if (root)` instead.

Comment: You're right, I completely forgot to run it down the list if there was a collision. I threw in a traversal statement just in-case there is a collision and it will search for the right string. The really weird part though is the `printFriends()`. I changed the `if(!root)` to `if(root)` (for some reason I threw a "!" there...), but I'm still not even getting any kinda of output.